# Definition of Irreducible Tensor Parts in an Exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus

I am addressing exercise 23.9 on http://www.pma.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2011/1023.1.K.pdf. The exercise says that a fluid flowing through spacetime $\vec u(\mathcal P)$ can have its gradient $\nabla \vec u = u_{\alpha;\beta} e^\alpha \otimes e^\beta$ decomposed into irreducible tensor parts as follows:
$$u_{\alpha;\beta} = -a_\alpha u_\beta + \frac13 \theta P_{\alpha\beta} + \sigma_{\alpha\beta} + \omega_{\alpha\beta}$$
where, according to the textbook itself

- $P_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\alpha\beta}+u_\alpha u_\beta$ is definition of $P$,
- $\sigma_{\alpha \beta}$ is symmetric and trace-free, and is orthogonal to the 4-velocity
- $\omega_{\alpha\beta}$ is antisymmeric and is orthogonal to the 4-velocity.

Indeed $P$ is defined clearly as in above, but $a_\alpha, \sigma_{\alpha\beta}, \omega_{\alpha\beta}$ are only given *descriptions* of their nature rather than *definition*.

And the exercise asks me to identify $a_\alpha$ with acceleration $\nabla_{\vec u} \vec u$, identify $\theta$ with $\nabla \cdot \vec u$, and lastly to derive formula for $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\omega_{\alpha\beta}$. However I found it impossible to proceed with the exercise, since it is nowhere clearly mentioned how these constants in the decompositions are defined at the first place!

I'd be very grateful to either receive any instruction on how these constants are defined, or any reference text / article I can read to clarify the issue.